# Horizontal Menu only with Image Css

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Am New to `Asp.net` and `CSS`.
I Need to Show Horizontal Menu only image like this

```
image 1  image 2  image 3 image 4
```

So I tried like this

**CSS**

```
 #UlIcon
   {
    height: 100%;
    list-style:list-style-image;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left: 5px;
   }

    #UlIcon li { display:inline;  width : 100px; height:100%;}

   #LiNew
   {
    list-style-image:url(/IMG/New.png);
   }

    #LiSave
   {
    list-style-image:url(/IMG/Save.png);
   }

    #LiDelete
   {
    list-style-image:url(/IMG/Delete.png);
   }

    #LiLog
   {
    list-style-image:url(/IMG/New.png);
   }
   #Padding-right {padding-right:15px;}
```

**ASP.NET CODE**

```
<div id="DivMenuRight">
                 <ul id="UlIcon">
                    <li id="LiNew"></li>
                    <li id="LiSave"></li>
                    <li id="LiDelete"></li>
                    <li id="LiLog"></li>
                 </ul> 
         </div>
```

But it shows empty. If I Remove `display: inline` in `li css`, the image shows vertically in center of the `div`. What am doing wrong here?
How do I get the solution?

Am using `Visual Studio 2008 and CSS2.1`

Comment: Is this ok? https://jsfiddle.net/t1ne9gkn/

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud thanks but image not showing just dot showing in my application

Comment: Here i show just your img link.You need to change the link for proper work.

Comment: i tried your code in my file that time also show dot only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the css `list-style-image` will place an image next to each point or listed text. it act as an image bullet

I am of the opinion you would like to have this

```
<div id="DivMenuRight">
   <ul id="UlIcon">
       <li id="LiNew">
          <img src="link1">
       </li>
       <li id="LiSave">
           <img src="link2">
       </li>
       <li id="LiDelete">
          <img src="link3">
       </li>
       <li id="LiLog">
          <img src="link4">
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

then you can use css to display all list elements inline-block

example `display:inline-block`

**here is a snippet**

```css
img {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
li {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="DivMenuRight">
                 <ul id="UlIcon">
                    <li id="LiNew">
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCjDQxLj9LSCLsCI2iCDEawZVlJ7tlRuBQDHenXo_KaFhdTUiTGw">
                    </li>
                    <li id="LiSave">
                       <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQqyRrA_-5TM0vpRU8BcTPFpGubyzgHGtvE9FQzpnVMPnKnoZwkmQ">
                    </li>
                    <li id="LiDelete">
                       <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcShZ_bYswgHlQLrUn8egsNTTZn5nCmSz1NcFmvtUzujpZhrBflUiQ">
                    </li>
                    <li id="LiLog">
                       <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCjDQxLj9LSCLsCI2iCDEawZVlJ7tlRuBQDHenXo_KaFhdTUiTGw">
                    </li>
                 </ul> 
         </div>
```